# Swift SKSpriteNode draw order

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, layer, skspritenode

I have some problems with SKSpriteNode. If I do this:

```
var node1=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"image1");
var node2=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"image2");

self.addChild(node1);
self.addChild(node2);
```

Then `image2` will appear in front of `image1` (and that is good).

But if I do this:

```
var node1=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"image1");
var node2=SKSpriteNode(color:UIColor.redColor(),size: CGSizeMake(0,0,300,300)));

self.addChild(node1);
self.addChild(node2);
```

Then `image1` will appear in front of `node2-rectangle`. Why does it do that?

Comment: If you have ignoreSiblingOrder enabled you will need to set the zPosition for your nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I’m surprised that even compiles—`CGSizeMake` should only take 2 arguments (width, height), as opposed to `CGRectMake`, which takes 4 (x, y, width, height). In other words, it looks like you’re creating `node2` with a size of `(0,0)`. Try …`size:CGSizeMake(300,300)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's documentation...

> The default value (of SKView's ignoreSiblingOrder property) is NO, which means that when
>   multiple nodes share the same z position, those nodes are sorted and
>   rendered in a deterministic order. Parents are rendered before their
>   children, and siblings are rendered from eldest to youngest. When this
>   property is set to YES, the position of the nodes in the tree is
>   ignored when determining the rendering order. **The rendering order of
>   nodes at the same z position is arbitrary and may change every time a
>   new frame is rendered** [emphasis added].